# Laravel Multiple Image Upload using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, image-processing

I have been trying to upload multiple images in Laravel 4, using jQuery & Ajax without the page refreshing, with the progress bar, remove button and review (display the uploaded thumbnail where remove deletes it from the DB).

I have taken many approaches, (http://packalyst.com/packages/package/sukohi/surpass) (despite following every step, still doesn't work). Another approach I used (https://gist.github.com/filip-adriginal/bd397c5ec22a5916a966#file-gistfile1-txt) and tried the jQuery-File-Upload.

I am able to upload multiple images using (using foreach in the Controller):

```
 {{ Form::file('image[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }}
```

I have also looked at videos, tutorials and blogs, but they either had partial information or unsolved problems.

If anyone could give me some sample code, or point me in the right direction, that would be great! Thanks everyone for any help, really appreciate it.

Comment: First, you should get the images uploading w/o AJAX. Just my opinion especially starting out.

Comment: What is not working for you at the moment? when you define the file input name as array you should receive the files as an array on to the controller. run a for loop on Input::file['image'].

Comment: The upload is working great, I am able to upload multiple images to specific folders, but I have no idea how to use Ajax, with {{ Form::file('image[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }} I can also store their names and locations in the database, but when I looked at how to implement it with Ajax, it looks like I have to change all of my code.

Comment: Taylor otwell the man behind Laravel has always said if you're not comfortable with certain features of Laravel you can always change things here and there. I personally hate blade. It's a mess. You should try it with regular form html syntax and see if it works.

Comment: I actually got it to work up to a certain point with:
`code`
<script>
       var form = document.querySelector('#ajax');

       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

       form.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData(form);

        request.open('post', 'submit');
        request.send(formdata);

       }, false);

     </script> `code`
**Now I am getting a 405 MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thanks everyone for the help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try DropzoneJs. I think it is the best upload JS plugin

Answer (score 1):

[Howto : AJAX multiple file upload in Laravel](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/) is a great tutorial using `Dropzone.js`, check it. Also take a look at this tutorial [Laravel Ajax Multiple Image Upload and Preview](https://xuri.me/2014/06/05/laravel-ajax-multiple-image-upload-and-preview.html) which uses `Dropzone.js` as well.